# Data loss in SSIS package

Tags: ssis, truncation

I inherited a SSIS package that pulls data from table 1 to table 2 to table 3 and finally a destination(T0) table. Table 3 and T0 has the same data structure but has different data type. For example. T3 and T0 both has a column named Stime. But T3 is double float and T0 is a numeric.

For the Stime the data type will be all 250.0000000000000 something like that.
Now when I ran the sql. The particular record is in T1,T2,T3. But not in T0.

I was first thoughts because of the data type mismatch in T3 and T0. T0 drops the data randomly. But someone told me that since the records will be in  250.0000000000000 type. The SSIS only truncate it instead of drop it.

Is it true? So, does anyone knows SSIS truncate which type of the data or drop which type of the data?
TY~

I tried to add the data conversion...

Comment: Can you please post 1) the DDL for the tables in question 2) A screenshot of the Control Flow of the package 3) A screenshot of the data flow(s) of the package